# How to Rotate Only One View Controller to Landscape Orientation in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, iphone, rotation, ios13

I am trying to rotate one view while all other views are fixed to portrait.

I tried this above code, and It works perfectly in iOS 10, 11 and 12.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
//    //Solution 1:
//    UIViewController *controller = [self topViewController:window.rootViewController];
//    if ([controller respondsToSelector:@selector(canRotate)]) {
//        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
//    }
//    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    //Solution 2
    if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[LLViewController class]])
    {
        LLViewController *secondController = (LLViewController *) self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        if (secondController.isPresented) {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
        }
        else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In iOS 13, my view controller(LLViewController) can rotate. But first time I go to that view controller(LLViewController), the UI is in Portrait. I must rotate device again.
How to fix it?

Comment: maybe ... for iOS13.. you must set your LLViewController to have `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` - something like this `yourModalController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;`

Comment: Yes. This is correct answer. I fixed it.